# Буфер — это обязательно Heap?

Tags: winapi, ассемблер, указатели

Здравствуйте, скажите пожалуйста, вот во многих (по крайне мере которые я встречал) строковых-`winapi`'шных функциях следует передавать указатель на некий буфер, буфер обязательно должен быть заранее выделенной кучей (Heap)? Можно отправить указатель например на заранее зарезервированный массив байт?

Comment: Разумеется можно использовать любую память. Так что выделяйте в любом сегменте, хоть в стеке

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Лишь бы эта память была корректна во время работы с ней (ну и, конечно же,  доступна для записи-чтения :)).

Например, при выделении памяти в стеке следует не забывать, что она будет корректна только до окончания вызова функции.

А так - что выделите, то и годится :)